# Ubuntu 9.10 espeak error

Tags: ubuntu, espeak

Running Ubuntu 9.10 and trying to run the `espeak` command and I get this error 4 times:

```
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [thread from Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1136720) is this problem related with Bluetooth...go to System -> Administration -> Services and turn the Bluetooth services back on.

Ter Rymon also suggests in this thread, that a another workaround (for a follow-up problem which you may encounter, output is too fast or cut) is as followes:

```
%words = "hello world"
espeak --stdout %words | aplay
```

or you install the [GNOME espeaker frontend](http://gespeaker.googlecode.com/files/gespeaker_0.6_all.deb).